# Get the text of a page?

Tags: jquery

How do I use jQuery's $.get to collect the text shown on the page? The link I provided has a page with the text 'true'. How do I alert the text of the page? This is my code, thanks

```
$.get( "http://api.roblox.com/ownership/hasasset?assetId=52454955&userId=1", function( data ) {
  var x = $( "body" ).text( data );
  alert( x );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback parameter has the page contents so:

```
$.get( "http://api.roblox.com/ownership/hasasset?assetId=52454955&userId=1", function( data ) {
  alert( data );
});
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.roblox.com/ownership/hasasset?assetId=52454955&userId=1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.roblox.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: That's the error I get when doing this on any page. When I do it on the actual website, I get "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: `TypeError: undefined is not a function` probably means jQuery is not loaded correctly. The other error means the page you're requesting doesn't allow cross domain requests.

Comment: @Sam You may find **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10143166/2311559)** useful.